# Why do we only have a "my tags" tab on unanswered questions?

Tags: feature-request, tags, sorting, my-tags

The "my tags" tab is really useful, but I'd also like to be able to see answered questions on topics I'm interested in.

Why isn't there a "my tags" tab for all the questions?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too many (as I believe there is a limit on how many search parameters you can use, something like 10 actual terms), a workaround is to simply do a large tag search joined by OR operators. If you only work off of your own machinery then it's also recommendable to add this search to your bookmarks, preferably on a toolbar. So, if your interesting tags were, say, [c++] and [*arrays] on Stack Overflow, the search string would be:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C%2b%2b+OR+~arrays

The drawbacks of this method are less efficiency if you work on multiple stations (you may not have the luxury of bookmarking) and poor support for extensively large interesting tag lists.

However, one very good advantage of this method is that you can apply this search filter to every sort tab. So instead of being restricted to whatever sorting the "My Tags" tab would be in, you can sort your interesting filtered results by "Newest", "Active", "Featured", "Votes", and "Hot", making it very versatile as well as directly adhering to whatever your standard sort method is when browsing.

If you can also put this on a bookmark toolbar on your browser, then this also has an advantage of allowing you to access the search parameters directly from whereever you might be, not to mention just plain opening your target site with your desired filter on the get-go.

Comment: I foresee a "tl;dr" in the near future for this community bump...